# SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Search - can I search for forward-slash characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I'm trying to use SQL Server 2005's Full-Text Search to find single forward-slash characters within my indexed column, without success.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible at all?  Example:

In my `CentralSearchCache` table, the `SearchData` column contains a row with the text "This/string/contains/forward/slashes".

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM FREETEXTTABLE(CentralSearchCache, SearchData, 'forward/slashes')
```

returns data, whereas this query:

```
SELECT * FROM FREETEXTTABLE(CentralSearchCache, SearchData, '/')
```

returns nothing.  Is there any way of finding rows that contain one or more forward-slash characters?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely NOT. Full TEXT search is for TEXT. It is not possible to search for text delimiters and even specific words that are "kill words" (like "in", "on" etc. - that are happening way too often and that every non-trivial text will have anyway).

Whther or not "/" is filtered out is a question, bit I would somehow bet it is.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that might be the case.  The forward-slash isn't contained in the Noise Words file, but I guess it's classed as a delimiter and therefore isn't searchable.  Thanks anyway!