# Search for forward slash within a SQL Server Full Text Index using Contains

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, special-characters, contains

I have a SQL Server full-text index and I'm attempting to search for phrases using `CONTAINS` such as `/cap` contained within the data. However, SQL Server seems to strip off the `/` and only return results contain `cap`. How do I stop this from happening so that I can have exactly what I am searching for returned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Search - can I search for forward-slash characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652197/sql-server-2005-full-text-search-can-i-search-for-forward-slash-characters)

Answer (score -1):

Please use like operator

```
CREATE TABLE temp(
   sometext nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO temp

SELECT 'I contain /cap and cap'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dummy'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CAP'

SELECT sometext FROM temp
WHERE sometext LIKE '%/cap%'

SELECT sometext FROM temp
where sometext like '%cap%'
```

Results:

```
sometext
--------
I contain /cap and cap

sometext
--------
I contain /cap and cap
CAP
```

Comment: Thus negating the entire point of using full-text in the first place.