# Full Text Search of URL field sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

Objective: Return all URLs beginning with `"https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4/"`

Given:

- Applied full text search on URL field.
- SQL Server edition: 2014.
- 20+ Million rows

### **URL**

```
https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/1/production
https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/2/items
https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/1/affordability
https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/3/summary
https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4/schedule
https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4/resources/summary
```

**Query 1:**

```
WHERE CONTAINS (URL, 'https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4')
```

Result:

```
All records returned
```

**Query 2** (Added "*" after reading [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583(v=sql.120).aspx#Simple_Term))

```
WHERE CONTAINS (URL, '"https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4*"')
```

Result:

```
No records returned
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is url column always starting with `https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/` or at least with `https://mywebsite.domain.com`?

Comment: Yes each record starts with the protocol and domain.

Comment: ok, but domain and protocol are fixed?

Comment: Correct, they are fixed.

Comment: also `/as/product` is always present? or could be different?

Comment: Anything after the domain and protocol could be different.

Comment: so you are looking for all url of a specific product number? for example 4?

Comment: I am matching any value after the domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `CONTAINS` with a `LIKE` subquery for matching only a start:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM myTable WHERE CONTAINS (URL, '"https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4/"')
) AS S1 
WHERE S1.URL LIKE 'https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4/%'
```

This way, the **SLOW** `LIKE` operator query will be run against a smaller set of records

**EDIT1:** (if `WHERE CONTAINS (URL, '"https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4/"')` is not filtering Values)

After a lot of searches. the problem is in `/` . The forward-slash isn't contained in the Noise Words file, but I guess it's classed as a delimiter or Word breaker and therefore isn't searchable.

**Read these Topics:**

- [experts-exchange Topic](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26623838/Full-text-search-does-not-return-results-for-search-query-with-forward-slash.html)
- [Stackoverflow Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652197/sql-server-2005-full-text-search-can-i-search-for-forward-slash-characters)
- [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.fulltext/afMbB8bHWDQ)

**EDIT2:**

**I found one suggested solution that is**

`/` is considered as an english wordbreaker You may change It from Registry

- Navigate to Registry values
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\<InstanceRoot>\MSSearch\Language\eng`
  and 
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\<InstanceRoot>\MSSearch\Language\enu`
- clear value for WBreakerClass.

Sql server consider `https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4` as one word.

**Note:** above both path i have taken by assuming that you are using English language as word breaker.

Read more about Word Breaker in This [MSDN Topic](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509108(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: As [MtwStark](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4523896/mtwstark) commented on [Rafael](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7158441/rafael)'s answer, we should add a slash before `%` or it will find also 44, 4xyx... the OP needs `.../4/%`

Comment: @WorkSmarter you don't need any full text search, drop full text index, put a standard non clustered index on your url column and use only the `LIKE` operator. the `CONTAINS` is only a needless overhead. With the index on url column `LIKE FixedPattern+%` is performed with index seek, you cannot improve it any further (maybe unless you set that index itself as clustered) see my answer for further details

Comment: The downside to this approach is that SQL Server [performs the `LIKE` scan first, and then merges it with the results of the `CONTAINS`](https://i.imgur.com/VlkJItm.png) - meaning that the slow `LIKE` operator is always run against all rows first, in addition to the full-text query.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Like` operator:

```
WHERE URL LIKE 'https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4%'
```

The `%` is a wildcard. This should return all records that start with a pattern match up to the first wildcard `%`.

Comment: Let me be the first to welcome you to StackOverflow.  Smaller record sets work great with "Like".  However, when working with millions of records, the "Like" operators performance becomes an [issue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx#Anchor_4)

Comment: What about replacing the start of the string `https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/` with a blank, leaving the start of your string as `4/etc/etc`  ? The `LIKE` operator may perform better when only traversing one character. A simple - try and fail fast - suggestion.

Comment: @WorkSmarter on indexed columns, searching a string from beginning is very fast also with `LIKE` operator, take a look at my answer

Comment: you should add a slash before `%` or it will find also 44, 4xyx... the OP needs `.../4/%`

Comment: I agree with MtwStark that an index should make prefix queries with LIKE operator perform very fast, **provided** it's a clustered index (i.e. B-tree), as this indexes strings in lexicographical order. A hash index or similar will not help with prefix search.

Comment: @HenningKoehler the index will perform very very fast also if not clustered and also without a clustered index present and also without a primary key. the index is b-tree itself, clustered or not it's only about the physical order of data.

Comment: Hmm.. re-reading the description I'd say you are right, non-clustered indexes have b-trees as well. So just avoid explicitly creating a hash-index.

Comment: @WorkSmarter: Although a FULLTEXT index will be remarkably faster than a `LIKE` in the majority of situations where you are looking for some random part of text, `LIKE` will easily beat out FULLTEXT when you are specifically searching for the start of a an indexed string column. You can do that different ways, but MtwStark's 2nd and 3rd approach get my vote. It's going to be faster, easier to set up and save you a gazillion on resources and frustration with the FULLTEXT.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you always search start of the string this will ensure optimizer can use index. I assume URL is VARCHAR

```
Declare @p varchar(500) ='https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4'

Declare @maxChar char(1);
select @maxChar = max(ch)
from (
    select top(256) ch = char(row_number() over(order by (select null)) - 1)
    from sys.all_objects) t;
select @maxChar;

-- ..
WHERE URL > @p AND URL < @p + @maxChar
```

When comparing strings, Sql server adds trailing spaces to the shorter one. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626 . According to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt , http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt all allowed URL symbols are greater than space. So the search parameter, `'https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4'` for example, will be less than any URL which starts with this parameter and exceeds parameter length.

Comment: Why using CHAR(255)?

Comment: Good point, and it can be collation specific. See edited answer, compute @maxChar first.

Comment: did you have a reference for comparing varchar using comparaison operators `>` `<` `<=` `>=` `=` and if it benefits from indexes?? i am really interested. And

Comment: After searching. when using `Like` predicate to search start of string `Like 'xx%'` it uses indexes also.

Comment: The difference is `'1' like '1%'` is true, `'1' >'1'` is false, OP needs only URL which start with but not equal to the search parameter.

Comment: if you have index on url, this is not better nor faster than `where url like 'https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4/%'`, if you have no index the best option would be `where substring(url, 30, 13) collate latin1_general_bin = 'as/product/4/' collate latin1_general_bin`

Comment: sorry, maybe I have lost something, where did you read "but not equal to" ?

Comment: @MtwStark. May be just I'm misunderstanding something. I look at URL samples as a representative set and it doesn't contain ones equal to search parameter.

Comment: 1st line of question, Objective: Return all URLs beginning with `"https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4/"` the search string itself is included

Answer (score 2):

For similar problems I'm used to two solutions, depending on your needs, mainly on performaces or resources or concurrency.. etc etc..

The `LIKE` operator could be your best friend also with very big tables.

**Indexing**
First of all, you need to index your url column, working with 20+ millions records it is not easy task, 
indexing it could cost you 1.5 - 2.0 Gb of disk space, 
but you will get your query in NO TIME (milliseconds)

With the index on the column to search, `LIKE FixedPattern+%` is performed with an index seek, **you cannot improve it any further**.

**First solution:**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_URL] ON [url_table] ([url]);

DECLARE @Domain VARCHAR(100) = 'https://mywebsite.domain.com/'
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(100) = 'as/product/'
DECLARE @Product VARCHAR(20) = '4'
DECLARE @LikeAll VARCHAR(100) = @Domain + @Path + @Product + '/%'

SELECT url
FROM url_table
WHERE url LIKE @LikeAll
```

**Second solution**
The second option is a bit tricky but very effective.
You said protocol and domain of url are fixed and you need to search for something after.
The following is a technique, you can fine tune it to match your needs.
The idea is to add a virtual (computed) column to your url table and then to add an index on it.
This will greatly reduce index dimensions and improve query performances at the cost of a very little overhead of computing in insert/update

```
ALTER TABLE url_table ADD path AS (SUBSTRING(url, 30, 4000));
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PATH] ON [url_table] ([path]);

DECLARE @Domain VARCHAR(100) = 'https://mywebsite.domain.com/'
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(100) = 'as/product/'
DECLARE @Product VARCHAR(20) = '4'
DECLARE @LikeMid VARCHAR(100) = @Path + @Product + '/%' 

select @Domain + _path -- pay attention!!
FROM url_table
WHERE url LIKE @SrcAll
```

Please take note, we are selecting  @Domain + _path instead of url, to avoid table access and work only on index data.

If you need other columns in url_table your best option is

```
declare @l table (id int primary key)
insert  into @l
select id 
from url_table 
where _path like @LikeMid

select url
from url_table
where id in (select id from @l)
```

very fast

**Third solution**
This is a variant of second one.
In your example data I see the path contains `/product/` followed by a number and I'm assuming it as the product number.
Maybe you can consider the following

```
ALTER TABLE url_table ADD _product AS (cast(substring(url,nullif(CHARINDEX('/product/',url,29)+9,9), CHARINDEX('/',url,nullif(CHARINDEX('/product/',url,29)+9,9))-nullif(CHARINDEX('/product/',url,29)+9,9)) as bigint));
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PRODUCT] ON [url] ([_product]);

select id, url
from url_table 
where _product = 4
```

This will produce a computed column with product number of type integer, the index will be only 500Mb and queries on integers will be super fast.
Also the overhead to select all columns from url_table is very very little so you can `SELECT *` with almost no performances issues.

P.S.
You can drop your FullText index and save space and resources..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE URL LIKE 'https://mywebsite.domain.com/as/product/4%'
```

Comment: need additional `/` before `%`